# Analyze a Singularity

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=\frac{e^z}{1+z^2}$ be given. It has a two isolated singularities $\{i,-i\}$.

I know from the Laurent expansion that it has poles of order 1 at these points. However, I want to proof this not using the Laurent expansion.

This means I want to get to the following conclusion:

$\exists\ a_1,..,a_m\in \mathbb{C},m\in\mathbb{N},a_m\ne0$  so that

$f(z)-\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{a_k}{(z-a)^k}$

has a removable singularity at $a$. (In our case these would be $\{i,-i\}$)

Somehow all my approaches led to nothing and I could not show it this way.

Comment: This conclusion involves a Laurent series, so what ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Find $A, B \in \mathbb C$ such that
$$g(z) = f(z) - \frac{A}{z-i} -\frac{B}{z+i} \tag0$$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb C \setminus\{i,-i\}$ and with existing limits $\lim\limits_{z \to \pm i} g(z)$.

Comment: This is exactly what I wrote in my question. I simply can not find such a form, thats my problem

Comment: Knowing that $z^2+1=(z-i)(z+i)$. Multiply both sides of the equality $(0)$ by $z-i$ and replace $z$ by $i$. What do you get?

Comment: That $A=e^i/(2i)$. And $B$ could be obtained analogously, by multiplying with the other linear factor. I thank you for your hint and want to ask further, what if I didn't know anything about the singularities, e.g. must only work with $f(z)$. Is there a way to get to the same result? Note that I only have to show the existence of a series (0) but dont actually have to compute the coeffiecients.

Comment: In fact, you have at least to identify the singularities. And this is easy in your case when you analyze $f$. Singularities of $f$ are when $z^2+1$ vanishes as you noticed. You can also notice that $A = \lim\limits_{z \to i} f(z)(z-i)$ and similarly for $B$.

Comment: Do you mean by "identify", to determine whether they are poles or removable or even an essential singularity? I could solve similar examples quite easily by just modifying the series into the mentioned form. But these "modifications" seem to be a lot harder with this one.